# use incremented class name to apply classes to a similarly named div

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, input

I'd like to manipulate a div based on a text input with a similarly named class.

for example if the input is named foo1 I'd like div1 to be manipulated and if the input was foo2 i'd like div2 to be manipulated.

here is the code snippet I am using:

```
var i = (i + 1);
$('.pI_nameText + (i) ').focus( function() {
    $(".nameLights + (i) ").addClass("lightOverlay"); });
$('.pI_nameText + (i) ').blur( function() {
    if ($(".pI_nameText + (i) ").val() == '') {
        console.log($(".pI_nameText + (i) ").val());
        $(".nameLights + (i) ").removeClass('lightOverlay')
    }
})
```

here is a fiddle for this code:http://jsfiddle.net/W99vQ/

I'm nearly there I think , as this works without the incrementing, but not with it, so it should be the syntax I'm using.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BLZRX/1/

Comment: That's awesome, here is my updated fiddle to use the code you have in a manner that actually does something :)
http://jsfiddle.net/6cte3/1/
Thanks so much!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better to group the elements with a common class and use it as a selector like

```
<input class="pI_nameText name1"></input>
<div class="nameLights"></div>
<input class="pI_nameText name2"></input>
<div class="nameLights"></div>
<input class="pI_nameText name3"></input>
<div class="nameLights"></div>
<input class="pI_nameText name4"></input>
<div class="nameLights"></div>
<input class="pI_nameText name5"></input>
<div class="nameLights"></div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.pI_nameText').focus(function () {
        $(this).next().addClass("lightOverlay");
    }).blur(function () {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $(this).next().removeClass('lightOverlay')
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BLZRX/)

Comment: One wrinkle I am running into is that I actually have each of these inputs wrapped by a div, so now it seems as though the "indexing" no longer works...http://jsfiddle.net/6cte3/3/

Comment: @sventizzle because now the target `div` is not the next sibling of the input, it is the next sibling of the input's parent... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6cte3/4/ - sometimes the traversing/selector s have to be changed if you change the markup structure

Comment: So you can access the "index" by using .parent().next()
that's great.  I'm really new to javascripting so these details are not part of my noobie knowledge.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @sventizzle probably you should go through http://api.jquery.com/ once... go through selectors, traversal and manipulation methods

Comment: I definitely will look at that more, I have tried reading documentation, but beiong an artist I learn through example, and the docs have some but maybe not enough, or at least not ones that SEEM appropriate.  How do I access the div + idx -1 ?  The code you provided seems to change the class on the "next" div not the current one...see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cte3/5/

Comment: @sventizzle not it is the previous sibling not next... so use .prev() like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6cte3/6/

Comment: thanks so much Arun, your help has been very welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate over all of the elemnents and then bind your handler.

```
for(var j = 1; true; j++)
{
  if($('pI_nameText' + i).length == 0)
  {
    break;
  }
  $('pI_nameText' + i).focus(function(){
    $(".nameLights + (i) ").addClass("lightOverlay"); 
  });
  $('.pI_nameText + (i) ').blur( function() {
    if ($(".pI_nameText + (i) ").val() == '') {
      console.log($(".pI_nameText + (i) ").val());
      $(".nameLights + (i) ").removeClass('lightOverlay');
  });
}
```

**But** I would strongly advise agains doing it this way! By looking at your fiddle, if you have access to the html, I would possibly add another class to your `pI_` elements like this:

```
<input class="pI_nameText1 anotherClass"></input>
<div class="nameLights1 anotherClass_Lights"></div>
```

then bind them all at once.

```
$('.anotherClass').focus(function(){
  $(this).next('.anotherClass_Lights').addClass('lightOverlay');
});
$('.anotherClass').blur(function(){
  $(this).next('.anotherClass_Lights').removeClass('lightOverlay');
});
```

Comment: plaese see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cte3/3/ and see if your code still makes sense, the inputs are all actually wrapped with divs...I'm thinking this would break the ability to increment